# WM_COPYDATA from VB.Net to Delphi 10.4

Tags: delphi, wm-copydata

I'm trying to move an application from Lazarus to Delphi 10.4. The problem I am having is with WM_COPYDATA.

On the VB.Net application:

```
        Dim sarr As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.[Default].GetBytes(msg)
        Dim len As Integer = sarr.Length
        Dim cds As COPYDATASTRUCT
        cds.dwData = CType(wParam, IntPtr)
        cds.lpData = msg
        cds.cbData = len + 1
        SendMessage(CInt(hWnd), WM_COPYDATA, 0, cds)
```

On the Delphi side:

```
    WM_COPYDATA :
       begin
            recvdata := PCopyDataStruct(Message.LParam);
            msgtype := recvdata^.dwData;
            msglen := recvdata^.cbData;
            str := StrPas(PCHAR(Recvdata^.lpData));
```

The msgtype and msglen are coming across fine, but the str (lpdata) is corrupted. I think this has something to do with Delphi using widechar or ANSI.

What do I need to do on the VB.Net and Delphi 10.4 sides to get them to line up ?

Thanks !

Comment: I don't have that version, but maybe `PAnsiChar` instead of `PCHAR`? - FWIW, I believe your analysis is correct.

Answer (score 5):

In Delphi 2009 and later, `PChar` is an alias for `PWideChar` (16bit UTF-16), but the VB.NET code is sending 8bit ANSI encoded bytes instead.  So, you need to use `PAnsiChar` instead of `PChar` on the Delphi side (unless you change the VB.NET code to use `Encoding.Unicode` instead of `Encoding.Default`).

Which BTW, there is a (potential) bug in the VB.NET code.  DotNet strings are not null-terminated, so `Encoding.GetBytes(msg)` will not output a null terminator byte if `msg` is a `String` (it will if `msg` is a `Char[]` array with a null terminator present).  The code is setting `cds.cbData = len + 1` as if a null terminator were present.  It should instead set `cds.cbData = len`.  And then, on the Delphi side, you can use `SetString()` instead of `StrPas()` to get the `PAnsiChar` data into an `AnsiString`, which you can then assigned to a native `string`.

Try this:

```vb
Dim sarr As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.[Default].GetBytes(msg)
Dim len As Integer = sarr.Length
Dim cds As COPYDATASTRUCT
cds.dwData = CType(wParam, IntPtr)
cds.lpData = msg
cds.cbData = len
SendMessage(CInt(hWnd), WM_COPYDATA, 0, cds)
```

```pascal
var
  ...
  astr: AnsiString;
  str: String;
...
  WM_COPYDATA :
  begin
    recvdata := PCopyDataStruct(Message.LParam);
    msgtype := recvdata^.dwData;
    msglen := recvdata^.cbData;
    SetString(astr, PAnsiChar(Recvdata^.lpData), msglen);
    str := string(astr);
    ...
  end;
```

Once that is working, consider using `Encoding.UTF8` instead of `Encoding.Default` to avoid any potential data loss of non-ASCII characters, since `Encoding.Default` is a locale-specific and potentially lossy conversion, whereas UTF-8 is a loss-less conversion:

```vb
Dim sarr As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg)
Dim len As Integer = sarr.Length
Dim cds As COPYDATASTRUCT
cds.dwData = CType(wParam, IntPtr)
cds.lpData = msg
cds.cbData = len
SendMessage(CInt(hWnd), WM_COPYDATA, 0, cds)
```

```pascal
var
  ...
  utf8: UTF8String;
  str: String;
...
  WM_COPYDATA :
  begin
    recvdata := PCopyDataStruct(Message.LParam);
    msgtype := recvdata^.dwData;
    msglen := recvdata^.cbData;
    SetString(utf8, PAnsiChar(Recvdata^.lpData), msglen);
    str := string(utf8);
    ...
  end;
```